# How do I change the retention period for the log files in websphere?

Tags: websphere, server.xml

How do I change the retention period for the log files from 1 day to 5?

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

// will get server location

// Name of the file

```
<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="9077" httpsPort="94710" />
<variable name="defaultHostName" value="000001" />

<!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
<enterpriseApplication id="Tiii.ear" location="Tiii.ear" name="Tiii_EAR"/>
<logging maxFileSize="20" maxFiles="4" copySystemStreams="false"/>
```

Comment: Hello RobinHood, and welcome to SO. I've edited the title of your question to better reflect what you are asking. We encourage to use a significative title, to help other people find answers and provide help more easily.

Answer (score 0):

How long the log files are retained for is configurable in number of files (`maxFiles` which you already have configured) rather than number of days.  Given that you mention you are currently seeing the files retained for about 1 day, an approximation would be to increase `maxFiles` from 4 to 20.  If that isn't sufficient, and you have a requirement for exactly 5 days, then you can open an a feature request against Open Liberty here:
https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/new/choose